# What is the name of this Israeli street food?

Tags: middle-eastern-cuisine, food-identification

When I was in Israel a few years back I tried this really great street food. I had gotten the recipe, but now have lost it and don't remember what it was called. It is a cross between a pancake and a bread. The one I had had za'atar, thin sliced tomatoes, and red onion fried into one side and was flipped over. Does anyone know what this is called?

Comment: Was it a latke, a potato pancake?

Comment: No it had no potatoes in it. It was pan fried if that helps anyone.

Comment: And it wasn't fresh pitta bread?

Comment: It wasn't pita bread. It was about the size of it, but had a more similar consistency to a hard pancake

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to track down the dish. It is called Lahuhe. There is a picture of it [here](http://pickuptheforkbuenosaires.files.wordpress.com/2011/08/mg_5093.jpg). Thank you to everyone for trying to help me out.

Answer (score 4):

From your description, it might have been a Malawach. [image]

If it is, [here is a link to a recipie.](http://recipes.epicurean.com/recipe/1974/malawach-%28israeli%29.html)

Comment: This is close, but the recipe is not right. There was nothing to dip it in or to spread on it. It just had the "toppings" embeded in the food.

Comment: What you had could have been simply a street-vendor variation on the base recipe (toppings baked into bread are easier to eat than those simply perched on top).  Perhaps you should try making this recipe -- with your toppings baked in -- to see if it tastes right to you.

Comment: Hmmm... it's possible that it was something invented by that particular street-vendor.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing this dish might have derived from manaqeesh (manouche) which are extremely popular all over the Levantine region, although it's spread all over now. In Melbourne, Australia, for example, there are dozens of Lebanese places that sell them.

Za'tar is the most popular flavour but there are many others such as sujuk, za'tar with tomato+onion, za'tar with veggies (capsicum, tomato, onion, olives, etc), cheese, kiskh, labne, minced lamb, spinach, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably just flatbread. If you are in an African (West and South) influenced area, it will be unleavened, just flour and water. In the more Middle East (North and East) areas it will probably have yeast as well (or local beer)

The dough is normally left to stand for some time before being rolled and cooked

They are rolled or teased out to large circles (50cm+), and then traditionally cooked over a convex curved pan (sag?). Imagine a upside down wok, made of thick steel

[image: Image from wikimedia commons]

On the Middle East side it is brushed with olive oil and herbs like Za'atar, or salt and chilli

If mixed and cooked quickly without leavening this is suitable for Passover, and is referred to as Matzo, but without the baked in toppings

Comment: The recipe did not call for it to stand to rise.